# 500 Server Error by Ajax and mysql

Tags: php, ajax

at first i want to say sorry for my "critical" english. i hope its good enought to a part of this communty. :)

I tried to code a chat with ajax/JQuery and PHP/silex.

This is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('data');
    setInterval(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: './../resources/controller/AjaxCom.php',
            type: 'POST',
            method: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            success: function () {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }, 1000);

    $.('form').submit(
        function () {
        var daten = $('#message').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: './../resources/controller/AjaxCom.php',
            type: 'POST',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {message: daten},
            success: function (daten) {
                console.log(daten);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error at writing');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the PHP File. This should communicate the Ajax, but i get this error:

```
POST http://localhost/chat/resources/controller/AjaxCom.php 500 
(Internal Server Error)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.js:
4n.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:4(anonymous function) @ ServerCom.js:7
ServerCom.js:15 error



<?php
namespace resources\controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class AjaxCom
 * @package resources\controller
 */
class AjaxCom implements AjaxComInterface
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $chatOutput = [];
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $userOutput = [];
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $ddConnect;


    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getChatOutput()
    {
        return $this->chatOutput;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getUserOutput()
    {
        return $this->userOutput;
    }

    /**
     * @param Application $app
     */
    public function __construct($datenbankVerbindung)
    {
        $this->ddConnect = $datenbankVerbindung;

    }


    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function showChatData()
    {
        $posts = $this->ddConnect->fetchAll("SELECT message,writer FROM messages");
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $this->chatOutput[$post['message']] = $post['writer'];
        }

        return ($this->getChatOutput());
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function showOnUser()
    {
        $users = $this->ddConnect->fetchAll("SELECT name FROM user WHERE status='1'");
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            array_push($this->userOutput, $user['name']);

        }

        return $this->getUserOutput();

    }

    /**
     * @param $message
     * @param $writer
     */


    public function writeChatDateInDb($message,$writer){
        $this->ddConnect->insert(
                'messages',
                array(
                    'message' => $message,
                    'writer' => $writer
                )
            );

    }
}
```

Can u help me to find the mistake? Thank u very much for ur help

Freemindghost

Comment: Where do you instiantate your class ? Put on error reporiing then open chrome's developers console, network tab and click the url to where the ajax request is made.

Comment: note: `type` and `method` are aliases of each other. it's totally redundant specifying both. and if you're getting a 500, go look at the server error logs for more details. it's pointless poking around in the code trying to GUESS what the problem might be, when you can be told what the problem IS.

Comment: Ok i will do it, thx